# Case object extending trait

Tags: scala, object

We can supply parameter to a class extending trait with the same name as an abstract method like

```
trait Trr{
   def m: String
}

case class Trrrr(m: String) extends Trr  //fine
```

This example compiles fine. But I tried to do something like that with case objects and failed:

```
trait Command{
  def name: String
}

case object Unload("unld") extends Command //compile error
```

Is there a way to write this concisely while leaving `Command` a trait, ***not an abstract class with parameter***? I mean not like that:

```
case object Unload extends Command {
  override def name: String = "unld"
}
```

or

```
abstract class Command(name: String)

case object Unload extends Command("unld")
```

Comment: There isn't another way that is more concise.

Answer (score 3):

```
case object Unload extends Command { val name = "unld" }
```

Object don't have arguments, things won't get any shorted than the above...

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate the trait directly like so:

```
val newTrr = new Trr { val m = "example" }
```

At this point you can use the newTrr value just like any class instance...

```
println(newTrr.m)
```

which will print out: "example".